# Android java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver Postgress database query

Tags: java, android, sql-server, postgresql

I am attempting to use a query in my android application for my postgres database, but I keep getting "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver" errors.

I have the driver in the dependencies so I am not sure what is happening.

Here is the code to use the query.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView resultArea;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    resultArea = new TextView(this);
    resultArea.setText("Please wait.");
    setContentView(resultArea);
    new FetchSQL().execute();
}
private class FetchSQL extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String retval = "";
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            retval = e.toString();
        }
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://**IPADDRESS**/postgres?user=postgres&password=**PASSWORD**";
        Connection conn;
        try {
            DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(5);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            sql = "INSERT INTO Users (username, password) VALUES ('poop','dick');";
            System.out.println("*");
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                retval = rs.getString(1);
            }
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            retval = e.toString();
        }
        return retval;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String value) {
        resultArea.setText(value);
    }
}
}
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "jett.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile files('E:/Alex Jett/Coding/160/MyApplication/libs/postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar')
}
```

Comment: The driver should be the JAR file in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in the dependencies:

```
compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1200-jdbc41'
```

and delete the line

```
compile files('E:/Alex Jett/Coding/160/MyApplication/libs/postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar')
```

Comment: I have exactly this and works, did you add the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> to the manifest?

Comment: I just added that, doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: In this line are you using the ip only, String url = "jdbc:postgresql://**IPADDRESS**/postgres?user=postgres&password=**PASSWORD**"; ? Use ip:port.

Comment: Other thing: Can you make a executeQuery with an INSERT?

Comment: I had that before, and everytime I get "org.postgresql.util.PSLQException: The connection attempt failed